# Stripe Webhook testing throwing ... Test webhook error: 500

Tags: php, stripe-payments

```
  require 'vendor/autoload.php';

\Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey('sk_test_51H9XLtEGCwEOAaDQ16lnivam11YlNQA8BqwOzAZLG7tu00oSLz8A6h');

echo "Hello World"; // to check whether endpoint is being hit by stripe. YES   $body = @file_get_contents('php://input'); $event_json = json_decode($body);
```

echo "$event_json";

?>

Comment: The 500 error code indicates something when wrong on your server.  Can you check your PHP and/or web server error logs for the error and provide details?

Comment: @JustinMichael thanks, this issue has been fixed but need to know how stripe webhook links with s2member (a wordpress plugin). thanks again.

Comment: If you have a new question you should post a separate question with as much detail as possible.

Answer (score 0):

fixed this issue, infact endpoint provided @ stripe wasn't right.